# How can I remove stopwords in sets od sentences?

Tags: python

I want to remove all stopwords from the sentences. I tried this but didn't work

```
def remove_stopwords(comments7):
text_clean = [word for word in comments7 if word not in stopwords]
return text_clean

data ['comments'] = data ['comments_tokenized'].apply(lambda x:remove_stopwords(x))
data.head()
```

And this error message came up

```
File "<ipython-input-22-b35451c69cb1>", line 2
    text_clean = [word for word in comments7 if word not in stopwords]
             ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: As the error says, correct your indentation and your code should work. Python is picky about this, for good reasons.

Comment: Also note that `lambda x:remove_stopwords(x)` is just a long way of saying `remove_stopwords`

Comment: Could you fix it through correcting the indentation?

Answer (score 0):

Correct [indentation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) is very important in python.
In your code it looks like all would be part of the 'remove_stopwords' function.

```py
def remove_stopwords(comments7):
    return [word for word in comments7 if word not in stopwords]

data ['comments'] = data ['comments_tokenized'].apply(remove_stopwords(x))
data.head()
```

I would suggest, you look if your ide makes 4 empty spaces if you press 'tab' because it can cause problems if you mix tabs and spaces.